# cocos2dx onKeyReleased gets called at keydown instead of keyup in android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am recently working with cocos2dx 3.0rc2 and I want to respond the back key event in android platform. I learned that I could override the onKeyReleased method of the layer and setKeypadEnabled(true) to capture the back key.

However I got a problem, I can capture the event, but not accurately. That is, I expect this method gets called when I released my finger from the back key. However it now gets triggered as soon as I put my finger on the back key. That being said, it responds at key-down phase while I wish it could do it at key-up phase.

Can you help me with this? By the way, I tested the code and it seemed that on win32, the backspace key was not responded (But it does not matter for me as I only care about android)

Here are the code blocks:

init:

```
...
this->setKeypadEnabled(true);
...
```

onKeyReleased:

```
...
if(keyCode ==  EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACKSPACE) {
    onBack(nullptr);
}
...
```

I also tried the other way to capture the event, by setting the listener instead of simply putting setKeypadEnabled(true). The result is the same.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written the correct code but have used the wrong key code.

It shoud be `EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_ESCAPE`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It has been a long time since I posted this questions and I will get a code to try it out!

Answer (score 1):

In our apps, we did like this:

```
auto obKeyBackListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
obKeyBackListener->onKeyReleased = [=](EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event)
{
    if (keyCode == EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_BACK) // KEY_BACK
    {
        event->stopPropagation(); // stop propagation for this event
        onBack(nullptr);        
    }
};
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(obKeyBackListener, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this->setKeypadEnabled(true);
```

with this:

```
auto keyboardListener = EventListenerKeyboard::create();
keyboardListener->onKeyReleased = CC_CALLBACK_2(HelloWorld::onKeyReleased, this);
this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(keyboardListener, this);
```